# Hadoop: error connecting to server, ipc.hbaserpc: 60020

Tags: hadoop, hbase

"ipc.hbaserpc problem connecting to server 60020"

I have used Hadoop framework where I have one master device and several slave devices. My framework was working fine but this morning, I suddenly found that I am getting this error" and hadoop is not working.

I checked the ip of master, it hasn't changed.

```
**netstat -nlpt | grep 60020**
tcp6       0      0 172.17.13.29:60020      :::*                    LISTEN      2766/java
```

> vi /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
172.17.13.29    master
172.17.13.18    slave
127.0.1.1       bt.foo.org      bt

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

> vi /root/hbase/conf/regionservers

```
master
slave

~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~
```

Please guide me in the right direction as to where the problem might lie.

Here is the Complete Error Message as I see it:

```
root@master:~/hbase/bin# ./hbase shell
HBase Shell; enter 'help<RETURN>' for list of supported commands.
Type "exit<RETURN>" to leave the HBase Shell
Version 0.94.6, r1456690, Thu Mar 14 16:32:05 PDT 2013

hbase(main):001:0> get 'profile', 'pranshu'
COLUMN                CELL                                                      
13/04/22 10:05:04 INFO ipc.HBaseRPC: Problem connecting to server: master/172.17.13.29:60020
13/04/22 10:06:06 INFO ipc.HBaseRPC: Problem connecting to server: master/172.17.13.29:60020
```

Answer (score 0):

Comment out the line "127.0.1.1       bt.foo.org      bt" from the /etc/hosts file on all the machines and give it a retry.And it's always better to provide the complete error log.

Comment: Commented it out and retried, not working though. Anything else you suggest?

Comment: That would be possible for me only after having a look at your logs.